# UIImageView Array ForEach Iteration Loop problem

Tags: swift, iphone, loops, foreach, swiftui

while developing my iOS app I encountered a problem with getting image in Array of UIImageViews to perform an action on that specific image. No matter which picture from my LazyVGrid photo collection I do LongPressGesture action on, it always applies to the first picture which is displayed. I think this might be an issue with the ids in my array that ForEach loop do not recognize each element properly, however I have no idea how to solve it.

I keep my array in ProfileViewModel class:

```
@Published var userPicturesView: [UIImageView] = [UIImageView]()
```

And I'm looping through it in my ProfileView:

```
ScrollView() {
                            LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: GridItem(), count: 3)) {
                                ForEach(0..<profileViewModel.userPicturesView.count, id: \.self) { imageIndex in
                                    if profileViewModel.userPicturesView[imageIndex].image != nil {
                                        Image(uiImage: profileViewModel.userPicturesView[imageIndex].image!)
                                            .resizable()
                                            .border(Color.black, width: 0.25)
                                            .frame(width: screenWidth * 0.34, height: screenHeight * 0.17)
                                            .onLongPressGesture {
                                                withAnimation {
                                                    self.shouldPresentEditActionSheet = true
                                                }
                                            }
                                            .actionSheet(isPresented: $shouldPresentEditActionSheet) {
                                                ActionSheet(title: Text("Edit selected"), message: nil, buttons: [
                                                    .default(Text("Set as profile picture"), action: {
                                                        withAnimation {
                                                            self.profilePictureImage = Image(uiImage: self.profileViewModel.userPicturesView[imageIndex].image!)
                                                        }
                                                    }),
                                                    .destructive(Text("Delete this photo"), action: {
                                                        withAnimation {
                                                            self.profileViewModel.deleteUserImage(imageIndex: imageIndex)
                                                        }
                                                    }),
                                                    .cancel()
                                                ])
                                            }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

I can add that I tried solving it by adding custom struct that holds my picture:

```
struct PictureView: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var uiImageView: UIImageView
    
    init(uiImageView: UIImageView) {
        self.uiImageView = uiImageView
    }
}
```

and then making an array of this structs in ProfileViewModel like this:

```
@Published var userPicturesView: [PictureView] = [PictureView]()
```

Then changing ProfileView in this way:

```
ScrollView() {
                            LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: GridItem(), count: 3)) {
                                ForEach(self.profileViewModel.userPicturesView) { userPictureView in
                                    if userPictureView.uiImageView.image != nil {
                                        Image(uiImage: userPictureView.uiImageView.image!)
                                            .resizable()
                                            .border(Color.black, width: 0.25)
                                            .frame(width: screenWidth * 0.34, height: screenHeight * 0.17)
                                            .onLongPressGesture {
                                                withAnimation {
                                                    self.shouldPresentEditActionSheet = true
                                                }
                                            }
                                            .actionSheet(isPresented: $shouldPresentEditActionSheet) {
                                                ActionSheet(title: Text("Edit selected"), message: nil, buttons: [
                                                    .default(Text("Set as profile picture"), action: {
                                                        withAnimation {
                                                            self.profilePictureImage = Image(uiImage: userPictureView.uiImageView.image!)
                                                        }
                                                    }),
                                                    .destructive(Text("Delete this photo"), action: {
                                                        withAnimation {
//                                                            self.profileViewModel.deleteUserImage(imageIndex: imageIndex)
                                                        }
                                                    }),
                                                    .cancel()
                                                ])
                                            }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

But this brought the same result.
Every help will be appreciated.

Comment: Don't use `actionSheet(isPresented:)` -- use `actionSheet(item:)` and pass the correct `PictureView` to it

Comment: @jnpdx Thanks for response! I'm trying to change my code to implement it your way however I'm not quite sure how to invoke Action Sheet in ForEach loop when longPressing on the image when there is no isPresented trigger

Comment: See my answer -- the trigger will be `item:` instead of `isPresented` -- just make sure to refer to `item` within the closure. Unrelated, but it's unclear to me why you're using `UIImageView` and then accessing the `image` inside it rather than just using `UIImage`

Comment: When I was using UIImage the same way as I'm using UIImageView now, my images would not display, maybe was doing something wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `actionSheet(item:)` instead of `actionSheet(isPresented:)` will give you access to the selected item. In iOS 14+, there are issues with `isPresented` rendering a previous value first. Here's a simplified version of your code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let pictureViews : [PictureView] = []
    @State private var selectedItem : PictureView? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(pictureViews) { pictureView in
            Image(uiImage: pictureView.uiImageView.image!)
                .onLongPressGesture {
                    selectedItem = pictureView
                }
        }.actionSheet(item: $selectedItem) { item in
            ActionSheet(title: Text("Edit selected"), message: nil, buttons: [
                .default(Text("Set as profile picture"), action: {
                    withAnimation {
                        //use `item` here
                    }
                }),
                .destructive(Text("Delete this photo"), action: {
                    withAnimation {
                        //use `item` here
                    }
                }),
                .cancel()
            ])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I implemented this in my code, adjusted ID creating so that I could also use removing by index and now everything works as it should have. If it weren't You I wouldn't have thought that the problem might be connected with ActionSheet :)